# How can I dynamically copy & paste a variable set of cells in Google Sheets to Docs?

Tags: google-sheets, documentation

I have been asked to create a script that can dynamically copy a set of cells in Google Sheets, then paste that data into Google Docs. What I am being asked to do basically involves...

1. Copy a varying amount of cells
2. Paste into a Doc
3. Recognize the phrase PAL as a page break in Docs.

I am under the impression that this is something that a binary script cannot do. I am more than open to being wrong, but there is nothing I can find that fits my bosses needs. He does not want this copying & pasting to be done manually, which seems like the only option to me.

Does anyone have any idea of where I could start?

Answer (score 1):

**Since you want to copy data from Google Sheets to Google Docs, the best idea in this situation is to make use of Apps Script.**

Apps Script is a powerful development platform which can be used to build web apps and automate tasks. What makes it special is the fact that it is easy to use and to create applications that integrate with G Suite.

**To copy the cells you will need to make use of the** [`SpreadsheetApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) **class.**

Some methods that can be used in this situation:

- [`getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) - used to get the range from where the values are taken;
- [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) - used to retrieve the values;

**To paste the values gathered from the sheet into the mentioned doc, you will need to make use of the** [`DocumentApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app) **class.**

Some methods that can be used to paste the values:

- [`getBody()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getbody) - used to retrieve the body of the document;
- [`appendParagraph(paragraph)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#appendparagraphparagraph) - appends a paragraph to the body;

**To recognize the mentioned phrase as a page break you can use the** [`findText(searchPattern)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findtextsearchpattern) **method.**

According to the documentation, this method:

> Searches the contents of the element for the specified text pattern using regular expressions.
>
> A subset of the JavaScript regular expression features are not fully supported, such as capture groups and mode modifiers.

Last but not least, you can also make use of [Apps Script triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) depending on your needs.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)
- [Sheet Class Apps Script - getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns);
- [Range Class Apps Script - getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues);
- [Document Class Apps Script - getBody()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document#getbody);
- [Body Class Apps Script - appendParagraph(paragraph)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#appendparagraphparagraph);
- [Body Class Apps Script - findText(searchPattern)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findtextsearchpattern);
- [Simple Triggers Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).

Comment: Is it possible to use getRange() in a way that identifies how many cells need to be copied over? It will not be the same amount every time. We have the PAL phrase but that will be an alphanumerical value. The Sheet will start with PAL0001, then PAL0002, PAL0003 etc. Is there a script command that can identify the cells in between two identifiers? And if so can I indicate that these identifiers are variables?

Comment: You can simply count the number of cells and afterwards use the returned parameter for the `getRange`. As for identifying the cells between two identifies, simply locate the range of the start and of the end identifier and retrieve the cells accordingly.

Comment: This is helpful, but unfortunately this still doesn't solve the issue. I am told that this script should require no interaction from my part after it is created. Have to count rows/cells would be too much interaction according to my boss. Edit: the reason counting wouldn't work is because how many rows/cells that need to be carried over will not all be the same. I understand that what I am looking for may be impossible.

Comment: The counting that I suggested is programmatical. You can either `1.` See how many cells are between the two identifiers by gathering all the values *until* you reach the next identifier and counting them at the same time; `2.` Copy *all* the values and then paste them onto the doc using string manipulation in order to separate the different values for the identifiers.

Comment: How would I go about doing these? And would the script possibly be confused by the PAL000X naming convention? Or would is there a line I could add to tell the script to ignore anything it has already copied?

Comment: This can be achieved by making use of the basic programming loops. In your situation two are required - one for looping through the identifiers and another one to loop through all the values.